# Setting JAVA5_HOME environment variable on Mac OS 10.5.8?

Tags: java, macos, classpath, guava

How does one install set the JAVA5_HOME environment variable for Google Guava libraries on Mac OS 10.5.8?

Comment: I have the tried the installing the Google Guava Libraries without success:

export JAVA5_HOME=/Library/Java/Home

export JAVA5_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Classes

BTW, I'm getting the following error message when I attempt to build the Google Guava Libraries:

$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

compile:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/conradwt/java.dir/projects/guava/build.xml:17: JAVA5_HOME must be set to a valid JDK 1.5 installation, containing a jre/lib/rt.jar file

Next, after doing several Google searches, it seems that
Apple may have split rt.jar into classes.jar and ui.jar

Comment: You should be able to get away with removing the stuff about JAVA5_HOME from your local copy of build.xml.  It's only there so that, if you're *editing* the library, you don't inadvertently make use of libraries that are from Java 6.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the end of `/etc/profile` (requires `sudo` access):

```
export JAVA5_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
```

If you have open terminal windows, you'll probably need to close and reopen them for this change to take effect.

Comment: Actually, it's probably something more like /Library/Java/Home. But otherwise, that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be set to:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Home
```

You can do this in your shell configuration file using something like:

```
export JAVA5_HOME='/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Home'
```

Comment: Don't set `JAVA_HOME` (or `JAVA5_HOME`) link to a specific version. The Java Preferences app on OSX dynamically points to different versions under different conditions. By setting to a specific version you may be asking for trouble.

Comment: It won't cause trouble if an app specifically *needs* Java 5. If your Java Preferences are set to Java 6, but an app used from the command line *requires* Java 5, then you do need to set `JAVA_HOME` (or `JAVA5_HOME`) to the actual location.

Comment: JAVA5_HOME environment variable is actually a build requirement for installing Google Guava libraries.